# Sqlite database Split table and search index in two files

Tags: database, sqlite

I have a Sqlite Database about 1.24 GB  that I want to optimize
I not make the database is give to me to make an app
The database have several index in each column make for fast search only 
there are no contrains exept one unique index ej

```
CREATE INDEX "numberF"
ON "fix" ("number" ASC);
CREATE INDEX "addressM"
ON "movil" ("address" ASC);
```

without the index the datase is about 400 Mb

I want to distribute the indexs an the table in separated file
and dont know if is posible in sqlite

schema:

```
CREATE TABLE "movil" (
"number"  TEXT NOT NULL,
"name"  TEXT,
"identification"  TEXT,
"address"  TEXT,
"province"  INTEGER,
PRIMARY KEY ("number" ASC)
);

CREATE INDEX "addressM"
ON "movil" ("address" ASC);

CREATE INDEX "identificationM"
ON "movil" ("identification" ASC);

CREATE INDEX "nameM"
ON "movil" ("name" ASC);

CREATE INDEX "provinceM"
ON "movil" ("province" ASC);

CREATE UNIQUE INDEX "numberM"
ON "movil" ("number" ASC);
```

Comment: Is that the only table?

Comment: No but doing with this table , I have  it

Answer (score 0):

You can't separate indexes from their table, they have to reside in the same file. But you can have separate files for each table. You can connect to one database file then [`ATTACH`](https://www.sqlite.org/lang_attach.html) others like this:

```
ATTACH 'c:\data\movil.db' AS movil_db;
```

Then when you're done with it:

```
DETACH movil_db;
```

Just be careful you don't break the limit of simultaneously attached databases. See the link above for that.